# A simple way to "bundle" .htm files containing x-jquery-tmpl templates?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-templates

My application performs a $.get of a half-dozen .htm files containing x-jquery-tmpl templates. I organized those .htm files based on areas of responsibility, which saved me from any scrolling-induced carpal tunnel during development.

I'm wondering if there's a way to "bundle" these .htm files at compile time, similar to the script/CSS bundling in MVC, such that it's only one HTTP request at runtime but still convenient for me to manage them?

Comment: How about treating each template as a _String_ and sending an _Array_ of _Strings_ using _JSON_?

Comment: Interesting thought, although it seems that route has the overhead of having to identify/parse templates rather than the client just getting an HTML block and appending it to the DOM. I'm also considering an MVC controller with one action+view that contains a bunch of partial views (the templates). I'll play with both ideas and see.